Tensors' add_ and __iadd__ difference in PyTorch
I can't figure out the difference between implementations of add_ method and dander __iadd__ method that pytorch tensor have.
So there is a lot of notations that doing
x = torch.randn(5)
x += 1
or
x.add_(1)

are absolutely the same.
However if you do this inside of your custom PyTorch class there will be a mistake like
ValueError: Cannot assign non-leaf Tensor to parameter 'XXXXX'. Model parameters must be created explicitly. To express 'XXXXX' as a function of another Tensor, compute the value in the forward() method.

or something similar.
So may be someone can tell what is the really difference between them? Why we can't replace each other in every situations? And what is the reason not implement them exactly the same?
I even tried to find the source code of it, but I looks too tough, it looks like that part of code has been written complitly in C++ and it's impossibly to have a look on iadd and add_ implementations.
So a big example of the code where += has to be replaced by add_ is bellow:
import typing as tp
from collections import OrderedDict

import numpy as np
import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST


N = 1024 * 16
VAL_SIZE = 512
TRAIN_SIZE = N - VAL_SIZE


class Flatten(torch.nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return x.view(x.shape[0], -1)


class CustomBatchNorm(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            num_features: int,
            eps: float = 1e-05,
            momentum: tp.Optional[float] = 0.1,
            affine: bool = True,
            track_running_stats: bool = True,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self._num_features: int = num_features
        self._eps: float = eps
        self._momentum: float = momentum
        self._params: tp.Dict[str, torch.nn.Parameter] = torch.nn.ParameterDict(
            {
                "weights": torch.nn.Parameter(
                    torch.ones(num_features),
                    requires_grad=affine,
                ),
                "bias": torch.nn.Parameter(
                    torch.zeros(num_features),
                    requires_grad=affine
                ),
            }
        )
        self._track_running_stats: bool = track_running_stats
        self._running_stats: tp.Optional[
            tp.Dict[
                str,
                tp.Union[torch.Tensor, int]
            ]
        ] = torch.nn.ParameterDict(  # to prevent "Expected all tensors to be on the same device..."
            {
                "mean": torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(num_features), requires_grad=False),
                "var": torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(num_features), requires_grad=False),
                "count": 0,
            } if track_running_stats else None
        )

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        x_dim_order: tp.Tuple[int] = tuple(range(x.ndim))
        dims_to_be_reduced: tp.Tuple[int] = x_dim_order[:1] + x_dim_order[2:]
        batch_mean: torch.Tensor = x.mean(
            dim=dims_to_be_reduced,
            keepdim=True,
        )
        batch_var: torch.Tensor = x.var(
            dim=dims_to_be_reduced,
            correction=0,
            keepdim=True,
        )
        if self.training and self._track_running_stats:
            correction: float = x.shape[0] / max(x.shape[0] - 1, 1)
            beta: float
            if self._momentum is None:
                beta = x.shape[0] / (self._running_stats["count"] + x.shape[0])
            else:
                beta = self._momentum
            # BOTH += HAVE TO BE REPLACED TO add_(...)  OTHERWISE THE ERROR WILL BE OCCURED IF IT'S RUNNING ON A DEVICE
            self._running_stats["mean"] += (beta * (batch_mean.view(-1) - self._running_stats["mean"]))
            self._running_stats["var"] += (beta * (correction * batch_var.view(-1) - self._running_stats["var"]))
            self._running_stats["count"] += x.shape[0]

        dims_to_be_unreduced = (1, -1) + (1,) * (x.ndim - 2)
        shift: torch.Tensor
        scale: torch.Tensor
        if self.training or (not self._track_running_stats):
            shift, scale = batch_mean, (batch_var + self._eps) ** 0.5
        else:
            shift = self._running_stats["mean"].view(dims_to_be_unreduced)
            scale = (self._running_stats["var"].view(dims_to_be_unreduced) + self._eps) ** 0.5

        x_normed: torch.Tensor = (x - shift) / scale
        weights = self._params["weights"].view(dims_to_be_unreduced)
        bias = self._params["bias"].view(dims_to_be_unreduced)
        return x_normed * weights + bias


mnist = MNIST("./", download=True)
X: torch.Tensor = mnist.data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28)[:N] / 255.
y: torch.Tensor = mnist.targets[:N]

X_train, y_train = X[:TRAIN_SIZE], y[:TRAIN_SIZE]
X_val, y_val = X[TRAIN_SIZE:], y[TRAIN_SIZE:]


device: torch.device = torch.device(
    "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
)

net: torch.nn.Module = torch.nn.Sequential(
    OrderedDict(
        [
            (
                'bn_test_0',
                # torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(
                CustomBatchNorm(
                    num_features=1,
                    eps=0.00001,
                    momentum=0.1,
                    affine=True,
                    track_running_stats=True,
                )
            ),
            (
                'conv_0',
                torch.nn.Conv2d(
                    in_channels=1,
                    out_channels=3,
                    kernel_size=(3, 3),
                    stride=(1, 1),
                    padding=(0, 0),
                    dilation=(1, 1),
                    groups=1,
                    bias=True,
                )
            ),
            ('bn_test_1', CustomBatchNorm(3)),
            # ('bn_test_1', torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(3)),
            (
                'act_1',
                torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
            ),
            (
                'pooling_2',
                torch.nn.MaxPool2d(
                    kernel_size=(4, 4),
                    stride=(4, 4),
                    padding=(0, 0),
                )
            ),
            (
                'flatten_3',
                Flatten()
            ),
            (
                'fc_4',
                torch.nn.Linear(
                    in_features=3*6*6,
                    out_features=10,
                    bias=True,
                )
            ),
            ('bn_test_2', CustomBatchNorm(10)),
            # ('bn_test_2', torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(10)),
            (
                'act_5',
                torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
            ),
            (
                'fc_6',
                torch.nn.Linear(10, 10)
            )
        ]
    )
).to(device)

loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
oprimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)
batch_size: int = 1024

number_of_epochs: int = 10

X_val, y_val = X_val.to(device), y_val.to(device)

for epoch in range(number_of_epochs):
    indexes: np.ndarray = np.random.permutation(TRAIN_SIZE)
    X_train, y_train = X_train[indexes], y_train[indexes]

    net.train()
    for i in range(0, TRAIN_SIZE, batch_size):
        oprimizer.zero_grad()
        X_batch = X_train[i:i + batch_size].to(device)
        y_batch = y_train[i:i + batch_size].to(device)
        y_pred = net(X_batch)
        loss_value = loss(y_pred, y_batch)
        loss_value.backward()
        oprimizer.step()
        oprimizer.zero_grad()
        # print(f"train loss value: {loss_value.cpu().item()}")

    net.eval()
    y_pred = net(X_val)
    loss_value = loss(y_pred, y_val)
    print(f"val loss value: {loss_value.cpu().item()}")

So if you run this and your computre has at least one cuda device, then you will have the error:
ValueError: Cannot assign non-leaf Tensor to parameter 'mean'. Model parameters must be created explicitly. To express 'mean' as a function of another Tensor, compute the value in the forward() method.

Can you give an example of code that produces the error? I ran your code with add_, ie self._running_stats["mean"].add_ and self._running_stats["var"].add_, and it didn't produce an error when running on GPU

@karl, as I wrote "So a big example of the code where += has to be replaced by add_ is bellow:" if you replace += to add_, it won't produce an error, but if you don't, it will.
And I'm wondering why

I've run your code with both the += variants and the add_ variants - neither produced an error when running on CPU or on GPU.
